# How do you output images of a repeater inside a group?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to output an image from a repeater inside of a group in Advanced Custom Fields but I can't get the image URL. The group is called 'Homepage' and the repeater is called 'Slideshow' with a field of 'background_image'.

Please see below code.

```
    $rows = get_field('slideshow');

    if($rows) {
        $image = get_field('background_image');
        $size = 'full';

        foreach($rows as $row) {
?>
            <li class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="bg parallax2" data-speed='.5' style='background-image: url("<?php echo $image['url']; ?>")'></div>
            </li>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

The background-image URL is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Fields inside a repeater would be called subfields (`get_sub_field`), so you code should be

```
      $rows = get_sub_field('slideshow');

    if($rows) {
        $image = get_sub_field('background_image');
        $size = 'full';

        foreach($rows as $row) {
?>
            <li class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="bg parallax2" data-speed='.5' style='background-image: url("<?php echo $image['url']; ?>")'></div>
            </li>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried that, but get_sub_field didn't work either. It isn't a field inside a repeater, it is a repeater inside of a group.

Comment: The slideshow should be `get_sub_field` as well in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$homepageFields = get_field('homepage');

$slideshow = $homepageFields['slideshow'];

if ($slideshow) {
    $size = 'full';

    foreach ($slideshow as $row) {
        $image = $row['background_image'];
        ?>
        <li class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="bg parallax2" data-speed='.5' style='background-image: url("<?php echo $image['sizes'][$size]; ?>")'></div>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try changing $size = 'full' to $size = 'large'. And make sure everything is inside the loop.

Comment: If the above measure works, it means that you don't have a predetermined size named as 'full'. If you don't need a specific size for your image and just want the original version, change $image['sizes'][$size] to $image['url'] and delete $size = 'full'; as you won't be needing it anymore.